# Mono Embedded migration to 4.0.4 and further support

Tags: c#, c++, mono, qt-creator, mono-embedding

i have migrated from mono 3.12 to the newer mono version 4.0.4.
http://www.mono-project.com/news/2015/05/04/mono-4-0-is-out/
Could someone point me to a mono embedded tutorial based on the new mono 4.0.4 release? I tried the simplest tutorial approach that i could find, i get every time a segment fault when i want to get a mono domain:

**project.pro**

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = MonoEmbeddedMinimal
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -pthread
CONFIG    += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += mono-2
PKGCONFIG += glib-2.0
```

**mono-2.pc**

```
prefix=${pcfiledir}/../..
exec_prefix=${pcfiledir}/../..
libdir=${prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include/mono-2.0
sysconfdir=/etc

Name: Mono
Description: Mono Runtime
Version: 4.0.4
Libs: -L${libdir}  -lmono-2.0  -lm -lrt  -ldl -lpthread
Cflags: -I${includedir} -D_REENTRANT
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <mono/jit/jit.h>
#include <mono/metadata/assembly.h>

int main(int /*argc*/, char */*argv*/[])
{
  mono_config_parse (NULL);
  MonoDomain *domain = mono_jit_init_version("app", "v4.0.30319");

  return 0;
}
```

**program output:**
    Native stacktrace:

```
    /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1(+0xd33ca) [0x7f68822413ca]
    /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1(+0x488e0) [0x7f68821b68e0]
    /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0(+0x10d60) [0x7f687fba4d60]
    /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1(+0x243a40) [0x7f68823b1a40]
    /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1(+0x24bef8) [0x7f68823b9ef8]
    /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1(+0x244f3f) [0x7f68823b2f3f]
    /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1(+0x244308) [0x7f68823b2308]
    /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1(+0x23af68) [0x7f68823a8f68]
    /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1(+0x23b851) [0x7f68823a9851]
    /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1(+0x245e6a) [0x7f68823b3e6a]
    /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1(+0x245f8e) [0x7f68823b3f8e]
    /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1(+0x1fc0a1) [0x7f688236a0a1]
    /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1(+0x1d079c) [0x7f688233e79c]
    /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1(+0x48f1e) [0x7f68821b6f1e]
    /data/canway/src/cw121/ASAP2Library/build-MonoEmbeddedMinimal-Desktop-Debug/MonoEmbeddedMinimal() [0x400805]
    /usr/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0) [0x7f687f278610]
    /data/canway/src/cw121/ASAP2Library/build-MonoEmbeddedMinimal-Desktop-Debug/MonoEmbeddedMinimal() [0x4006f9]

Debug info from gdb:

[New LWP 4935]
[New LWP 4934]
[New LWP 4933]
[New LWP 4932]
[New LWP 4931]
[New LWP 4930]
[New LWP 4929]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".
0x00007f687fba49bb in waitpid () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
  8    Thread 0x7f687792b700 (LWP 4929) "MonoEmbeddedMin" 0x00007f687fba107f in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
  7    Thread 0x7f687712a700 (LWP 4930) "MonoEmbeddedMin" 0x00007f687fba107f in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
  6    Thread 0x7f6876929700 (LWP 4931) "MonoEmbeddedMin" 0x00007f687fba107f in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
  5    Thread 0x7f6876128700 (LWP 4932) "MonoEmbeddedMin" 0x00007f687fba107f in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
  4    Thread 0x7f6875927700 (LWP 4933) "MonoEmbeddedMin" 0x00007f687fba107f in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
  3    Thread 0x7f6875126700 (LWP 4934) "MonoEmbeddedMin" 0x00007f687fba107f in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
  2    Thread 0x7f6874925700 (LWP 4935) "MonoEmbeddedMin" 0x00007f687fba107f in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
* 1    Thread 0x7f6882885840 (LWP 4928) "MonoEmbeddedMin" 0x00007f687fba49bb in waitpid () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0

Thread 8 (Thread 0x7f687792b700 (LWP 4929)):
#0  0x00007f687fba107f in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007f68823b9577 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#2  0x00007f68823b140a in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#3  0x00007f68823b7c44 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#4  0x00007f687fb9b4a4 in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f687f34113d in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6

Thread 7 (Thread 0x7f687712a700 (LWP 4930)):
#0  0x00007f687fba107f in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007f68823b9577 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#2  0x00007f68823b140a in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#3  0x00007f68823b7c44 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#4  0x00007f687fb9b4a4 in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f687f34113d in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6

Thread 6 (Thread 0x7f6876929700 (LWP 4931)):
#0  0x00007f687fba107f in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007f68823b9577 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#2  0x00007f68823b140a in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#3  0x00007f68823b7c44 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#4  0x00007f687fb9b4a4 in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f687f34113d in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6

Thread 5 (Thread 0x7f6876128700 (LWP 4932)):
#0  0x00007f687fba107f in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007f68823b9577 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#2  0x00007f68823b140a in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#3  0x00007f68823b7c44 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#4  0x00007f687fb9b4a4 in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f687f34113d in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6

Thread 4 (Thread 0x7f6875927700 (LWP 4933)):
#0  0x00007f687fba107f in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007f68823b9577 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#2  0x00007f68823b140a in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#3  0x00007f68823b7c44 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#4  0x00007f687fb9b4a4 in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f687f34113d in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6

Thread 3 (Thread 0x7f6875126700 (LWP 4934)):
#0  0x00007f687fba107f in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007f68823b9577 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#2  0x00007f68823b140a in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#3  0x00007f68823b7c44 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#4  0x00007f687fb9b4a4 in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f687f34113d in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7f6874925700 (LWP 4935)):
#0  0x00007f687fba107f in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007f68823b9577 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#2  0x00007f68823b140a in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#3  0x00007f68823b7c44 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#4  0x00007f687fb9b4a4 in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f687f34113d in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f6882885840 (LWP 4928)):
#0  0x00007f687fba49bb in waitpid () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007f6882241460 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#2  0x00007f68821b68e0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#3  <signal handler called>
#4  0x00007f68823b1a40 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#5  0x00007f68823b9ef8 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#6  0x00007f68823b2f3f in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#7  0x00007f68823b2308 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#8  0x00007f68823a8f68 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#9  0x00007f68823a9851 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#10 0x00007f68823b3e6a in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#11 0x00007f68823b3f8e in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#12 0x00007f688236a0a1 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#13 0x00007f688233e79c in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#14 0x00007f68821b6f1e in ?? () from /usr/lib/libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
#15 0x0000000000400805 in main () at ../MonoEmbeddedMinimal/main.cpp:21

=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```